# Google Analytics - User ID

Tags: google-analytics

Can I assign a User ID to every visitor in a property -regardless if they login or not?  How?  I have researched the subject on the web but I could not find a definite answer.  Google recommends to assign User ID only to visitors who sign in, but it is not clear whether this is a restriction.

Comment: Please do not ask many questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the user id is that is it set by a source unrelated to Google Analytics and that identifies the user reliably across browsers and devices, and allows to assign disparate sessions into a common dataset for that user id.

You can of course pass in a user id regardless. However if there is no mechanism in the background that reliably identifies the user then the user id is pointless. So unless you devise a mechanism that reliably identifies users without a login you **cannot use the user id feature **in any a meaningful way** (e.g. if you persist a user id in a cookie or in local storage you'd be effectively replicating the client id, which would be pointless).

So it is technically possible to pass in an arbitrary string or number, but it won't do you any good.

Comment: However by assigning a User ID to a visitor who did not signed in, I could see whether this visitor is returning to the site from a different device, something that the Client ID can not do.  Right?

Comment: But how are you to obtain a user id that identifies the user if he does not identify himself ? That's the reason Google recommends the login - that the user identifies himself is a prerequisite for having an id that is unique to the user in GA.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  By the way, can I use client ID as a dimension in my reports?  Client ID does not appear as a dimension in the Dimensions and Metrics Explorer, but I believe I can create a custom dimension that will store the Client ID.  My end goal is to have a row per customer/date+time containing the incidents associated with the particular customer at the particular time, e.g. page visits, particular events etc